# Rounded, transparent cutout area and background image, with CSS?

Tags: css, background-image, css-shapes

I am trying to code the attached layout (needs to be responsive and not use JavaScript if possible). I want to support IE8, or if not, a gracefully degrading solution would be great.

I found ways to make the semicircle cutout using pseudo-elements and border-radius, but the background image of the previous div needs to show through and I can't figure out how to do it. Please help!! I have highlighted the area covered by the background image, in case it is not clear. [Here is the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJIQw.jpg)

I got this far: https://jsfiddle.net/dcwoLb7f/

HTML:

```
<div id="first"><p>IMAGE CREDIT: WIKIPEDIA</p></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#first {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/VirtuellesStudio_Greenbox.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
p {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 40px;
}
#first, #second {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#second {
    background-color: blue;
}
#first:after {
    content: '';
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far...please provide code in the question

Comment: follow **Paulie_D** advice plz, else this might give you some ideas http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zeodD

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the question with a simplified fiddle and code.

Comment: Thanks for the codepen link, it's almost what I need but I don't understand how it works - you're putting the background on 3 different elements (.top, .tagbefore:before,
.tagafter:after) yet it shows as just one background. How?

Comment: the before element is just like your second element, the idea is to use the same background position. in your case since you know the height of the containers , then you may recalculate the position and use background-size, so they can match/overlap : exemple : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbLarK i could turn this in an answer, but i actually have some social interaction, might do this tomorow :)  SYL